# Grails Constraints are not creating view validation errors after move from 2.3.4 to 2.3.5

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am fairly new to GRAILS, using 2.3.5.

I have a fairly simple domain object:

```
class Product {
   String name
   ProductType type
   ProductType subtype
   String desc

   static belongsTo = [organization: Organization]
   static constraints = {
     name blank: false
     type blank: false
     subtype blank: false
     desc nullable: true, maxSize:1000
   }
}
```

I then have the following for the controller save action:

```
 def save(Product productInstance) {

    if(!productInstance.save()) {
        respond productInstance.errors, view: 'create'
    } else {
        request.withFormat {
            form {
                flash.message = "Product '${productInstance.name}' was created successfully!"
            redirect controller: 'product', action: 'index'
            }
            '*' {respond productInstance, [status: CREATED]}
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what constraint I use, I get the expected result, which is the DB insert will not succeed, but I don't get the errors trapped and sent back to the "create" view like I expect, I get the error.gsp page with a SERVER 500 Error stating the exception and the failed query.  Is there a setting I am missing?  I am just using the H2 DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save(Product product) {
    product.validate()    
    if (product.hasErrors()){
       log.error product.errors
       render view:'/product/create', model:[product:product]
       return
    }

    product.save(true)
    flash.message = "Product '${product.name}' was created successfully!"
    redirect controller: 'product', action: 'index'
}
```

Comment: this answer is correct, though my problem turned out to be the fact that the DB was not updating all the time in the background, so there were validation cases that were not being testing in the controller.  I am new to GRAILS and have found my way around the "best practice" for refreshing changes to domain in dev env.  Thanks for the answer though.